# Import of module 'glog.glog.log_severity' appears within namespace 'google' error in react native

Tags: react-native

tried every possible solution like:
use_modular_headers!

pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => false
pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec', :modular_headers => false

use_modular_headers!

pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => false
pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec', :modular_headers => false

use_modular_headers!

pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => false

use_modular_headers!

cd ios && pod install

but nothing worked for me

IS THERE ANY SOLUTION FOR THIS ISSUE??

Comment: did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

For other reasons, I actually added `use_modular_headers!` to my Podfile. Then this error occurred. So, I commented it out and the error went away.

Answer (score -2):

Me too  all of the above

expo 46.0.9
react-native 0.69.5 (bare)
node 14.15.4

...it was big problems, until I added this:

```
pod 'RCT-Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec', :modular_headers => false
```

...and it worked!